# command line client included in "SQL Server Management Studio 19"

Tags: ssms, command-line, sql-server-2022

With a web search I found that [`sqlcmd` is included in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008337/sql-server-management-studio-command-line).

Is there a command line client included in "SQL Server Management Studio 19"?

I wish to run some SQL scripts in an automated fashion.

I am not allowed to do a RDP Login on SQL Server 2022 (Provider managed).

**UPDATE after answer:**

```
Invoke-SQLcmd
Invoke-SQLcmd : The term 'Invoke-SQLcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-SQLcmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-SQLcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

and

```
Install-Module sqlserver
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'sqlserver'.
Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowershellGet\2.2.3\PSModule.psm1:9685 char:34
+ ... talledPackages = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQu
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powershell command Invoke-SQLcmd.
Example:

```
Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance Host\Instance -Database master -Query "select name from sys.databases where database_id<5"
```

If it's not present, open up PowerShell as an Administrator and install the sqlserver module by `Install-Module sqlserver`.

Comment: see my update. Those commands not working

Comment: Try the instruction :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module